# R table function - how to remove 0 counts?

Tags: r

I need to remove the rows from the table function output, which have 0 counts in all the columns. Is there any easy way to do that?

```
table(ds$animal,ds$gender)

___ | M | F

Cat | 9 | 4 

Dog | 0 | 0

Rat | 4 | 3
```

I just would like to see those rows:

```
___ | M | F

Cat | 9 | 4 

Rat | 4 | 3
```

Comment: Can you show us what `ds` would look like for an animal which has no gender entries?

Comment: Look at the `exclude=` parameter for `table()`. If you need more help, make a proper [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you need to drop levels from the factor animal.

```
table(droplevels(ds$animal),ds$gender)
```

you can also just drop them from ds and then do the table

```
ds$animal <- droplevels(ds$animal)
with(ds, table(animal,gender))
```

here I used with because it prints headers.

Answer (score 0):

I came over this answer that is helpful even 7 years later, and I asked myself, if this works with tidyverse as well. It does, which I would like to share.

In this specific case, I wanted to remove a factor level before computing percentages. And obviously, `droplevels` also works on the whole dataset.

```
ds %>%
    filter(animal != "Dog") %>%
    select(animal, gender) %>%
    droplevels() %>%
    table() %>%
    prop.table(margin=2) %>%
    kable(digits = 2, caption="Percentage of Cats and Rats")
```